# windows server 2008 issue

Tags: asp-classic, file-upload

i have a website in windows server 2008. I'm using aspupload component. the upload works when the file size is small but fails when the size is huge.

Is there some settings in iis 7 that limits the upload size?

-Vivek

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all your replies. I got this issue fixed.

I went to C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config

and added the following line under my website

```
  <security>
     <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1000000000"/>  
     </requestFiltering>
  </security>
```

thanks again

-Vivek

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search for your component brings us to this page:

http://www.aspupload.com/

Which lists the following limitation:

> files up to 2 GB can be uploaded

When I see a 2GB number like that, I'm inclined to think the limiting factor is a signed integer somewhere in their code.  Replacing that integer(s) with a Long would greatly increase the supported file size, if you have the ability to change that code.

Comment: Hi Joel. thanks a lot for the reply.

It seems to be working after i changed the timeout. But the progress bar is not appearing. im uploading a file of 300MB. the progress bar appears when the file size is like 20MB.

I tried the same file on a windows 2000 installation and the progress bar works great. Im just trying the progress bar code inteh samples folder that came with the installation. Pls help

Comment: So does it return an error message or does it just hang and never get there? If you look in the IIS logs both for the website and in the global HTTPERR folder do you see an error code?

Comment: it doesn't return an error message. the progress bar opens in a new window and shows no progress. closes by itself in 20secs. but the parent page still uploads. let me look at the iis log n getback

Comment: I checked the iis logs no errors. dunno how the progress bar works fine for 20mb file.

Comment: Only other thing I can suggest (apart from contacting the vendor) is to view the HTTP traffic with a utility like Fiddler to see if that sheds any light on things.

Comment: i looked at the http traffic usign the utility.

the progressbar in the popup screen comes from an asp page called bar.asp

it refreshes to show the progress. it just refreshes for 5 times and then stops for the big file. whereas in small file it refreshes until the upload is complete.

this is the main function called inside bar.asp
  bar_content = UploadProgress.FormatProgress(PID, TimeO, "#00007F", format)

it returns nothing after 5 refreshes and the prg bar window closes. its' a dll.

Comment: Is it still sending the binary data though? It looks like you can control the number of refreshes using the 2nd parameter if so http://www.aspupload.com/object_progress.html.

Comment: correct i changed that value from 10 to 100.. still no luck. the window stays but doesn't show any progress :(

Comment: actually it's not uploading after 99% of upload it gives this http://sourcecodezone.com/images/1.JPG

Answer (score 0):

AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed in metabase.xml for IIS needs to be changed.

This [link](http://www.banmanpro.com/support2/File_Upload_limits.asp) should help.